# Fatiar e armazenar dict em pyhon

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```py
class Buckts:

    def __init__(self, keys, palavras, tamanhoP):
        self.listaBuckts = dict()
        self.keys = list(keys)

        aux = list(zip(keys, palavras))
        self.aux2 = list()

        for i in range(0, len(aux), tamanhoP):
            self.aux2.append(dict(aux[i:i + tamanhoP]))
```

Que no método abaixo me retorna um dict (key + posição da mesma na aux2)

```py
   def criarB(self):
        for i, pag in enumerate(self.aux2):
            for v in pag.values():
                self.listaBuckts[v] = i
        return self.listaBuckts
```

O objetivo agora seria separar os elementos do dict a partir de uma função, todos os elementos devem ser armazenas de acordo com o resto da divisão da sua KEY por 10, ou seja se a key = 10 ela deve ser armazenada no bucktes[0] já que o resto da divisão é = 0.

```py
    def indexar(self):
        buckets = [[] for _ in range(10)]

        for i in self.keys:
            for ii in range(10):
                if i % 10 == ii:
                    buckets[ii].append(i)
        return buckets
```

O método acima é capaz de realizar a tarefa, mas apenas quando busco na lista de keys e não no dict lista.Buckts, a partir disso gostaria de quebrar o dict e não apenas a lista de keys:

Se precisarem de mais algum detalhe, não exitem em perguntar.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, amigo!
acredito que você está elaborando uma linha de raciocínio muito complexa para algo que deveria ser simples. Se ,no final, o objetivo é separar em listas, acredito que você deva fazer isso, de forma genérica:

```
def separador(item):
    return item%10
```

isso vai retornar um int que você pode associar ao seu local onde vai dividir.